# Why my div that is set to 100% in width doesn't want stretch to the width of the browser window when the page is scrolled?

Tags: html, css

Why my div that is set to 100% in width doesn't want stretch to the width of the browser window when the page is scrolled?

Comment: It should. Please post more code and information, maybe a direct link. You can edit your question to add information.

Comment: Ahhh, it is you, Voodie Pekker

Comment: Zeb gave an excellent answer, but as Pekka said, this should really work in a normal case. Could you post some more markup/CSS so we can maybe put together a solution that avoids tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand it, Div tags are not very good at stretching themselves to 100% of the width or height in comparison to Tables. Notice how nearly all of Microsoft's code uses tables as a base. I think if you put the div inside a table cell which has the correct width and then do width:100%; , that should do the trick. If you can.. have your master page based on a stretchable table.

Hope this isn't too far off what you're looking for.

Comment: And also, thanks for the info on Microsoft's heavy use of tables.