# div doesn't extend all the way to end of page when 100% width specified

Tags: css, html

I'm having an issue where I have certain elements whose width property I specified as being 100%.

This works nearly all the time.  However, when I resize the browser window such that you now have to *scroll* to the right side of the page to see the whole page, I notice that the div only extends as far as what was originally in browser's viewing area.

That seems to make sense I suppose but it looks really weird if the user decides to scroll to the right.  Is there some kind of workaround for this?  I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244713/why-my-div-that-is-set-to-100-in-width-doesnt-want-stretch-to-the-width-of-the) answer but I'm wondering is there another solution that doesn't use tables?

```
#header {
    height: 115px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #CDC1C5;
}
```

Comment: You can use `javascript` to achieve that.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your `body` and `html` tags are also stretched by 100%.

Try this:

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.box {
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#000;
    color:#fff;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
    box content
</div>
```

Comment: Can i take a look at your code? you have to remember that width is relative to its parent, in the case that i wrote the HTML is the highest parent you can have and the div will stretch as far as it will, which is 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Like andres said, make sure they body and any container divs are set to 100% and also make sure margins are set to 0, `margin:0 auto` I occasionally forget to do this, also if that fails you can do a bit of a "hack" and absolute position it:  `dividname {position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%;}` if this doesn't work and you are building live then send me a link, otherwise send me a screen shot if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Unrelated to the correct answer, sometimes it has nothing to do with the body nor the div itself, but maybe a totally unrelated element, what usually makes me find if that's the case, is to simply comment all the html within the body tag. Leaving only the div I want to check